# JNLP application with Java 7 - not starting

Tags: java, jnlp, java-7, java-web-start

I have a swing application which works fine as the desktop application but the same application when started using a jnlp, not starting without showing any errors

I have compiled using the classes using Java7 and created a jar and then after creating a jnlp file, started with javaws command as

```
javaws d:\jnlp1\val.jnlp
```

Then "Java 7" logo appears showing that the jnlp loading... after some 10 seconds, the javaws exits without any logs or errors

Can somebody let me know how to resolve this....

Thanks in advance

Comment: You realize that 7 is not considered 'production ready' yet, right?  Why does the app. need Java 7?  Did you validate the launch file with [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the missing jar and when the jar was added, the app works.